# Need help identifying SOT-23 component with marking S5NCA

Tags: surface-mount, sot23

I'm working on an active subwoofer made by Jamo. Subwoofer works normally but while in auto sleep mode it blows a fuse. I measured components off the PCB and only suspicious thing I found was this component.
Between two adjacent legs it measured something around 70 ohms. When I removed the component from the board the corresponding solder pads' resistance went up to around 70 kilo ohms. I couldn't find any information from the internet.

I marked the component's place with a red arrow.
The subwoofer is manufactured in year 2001 so it's an old component.

[image: Whole circuit board. RCA input on right.]
enter image description here[image: Close up of area near the component.]

[image: Picture of the component.]

Comment: Possibly [BFQ31A](https://www.digikey.com.mx/htmldatasheets/production/1862262/0/0/1/bfq31a.html) transistor?

Answer (score 0):

The markings match with a [Vishay SST175](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/47521.pdf) JFET.

[image]

I found a picture of the part that shows the style of the markings matches:

[image]
(Source: [ebay.com](https://www.ebay.com/itm/145139499782?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28))